# Не запускается асинхронная функция в потоке

Tags: python, aiogram, async-await

Концепция бота в том, чтобы он пересылал сообщения во все чаты, которые есть в бд и если конкретнее, то не получается выполнить await асинхронной функций в асинхронной функции, вылетает ошибка:

```
Task <Task pending name='Task-3' coro=<process_send_message() running at C:\Users\hdhrh\PycharmProjects\group_sendeer\main.py:92> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py:184]> got Future <Future pending cb=[shield.<locals>._outer_done_callback() at C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\tasks.py:857]> attached to a different loop
```

Код самой функции:

```
async def send_message_process():
    while True:
        try:
            with open("message.json", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
                data = json.load(f)["data"]

            all_users = db.get_all_users()

            for i in all_users:
                print(i)
                await bot.copy_message(from_chat_id=data[1], chat_id=i,
                                       message_id=data[0]) # в этой строчке происходит ошибка
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        time.sleep(60)
```

Потоки и их запуск:

```
def check_bd():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(send_message_process())
    loop.close()


def start_bot():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True))
    loop.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = Thread(target=check_bd)
    start_bot = Thread(target=start_bot)

    f.start()
    start_bot.start()

    f.join()
    start_bot.join()
```

Comment: Вроде как aiogram уже асинхронный, зачем там запускать в нитке ? start_bot = Thread(target=start_bot)

Comment: При этом коде:
```
start_bot = Thread(target=executor.start_polling, args=(dp,))
```
Происходит ошибка:
`
  File "C:\Users\hdhrh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 656, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2 (start_polling)'.
```

Comment: https://mastergroosha.github.io/aiogram-3-guide/quickstart/ - тут можно посмотреть, как через диспетчер от aiogram запускать бота

Comment: Спасибо, но мне нужно, чтобы и бот и эта функция работали одновременно, а при такой попытке:
`
async def check_bd():
    await send_message_process()


async def start_bot():
    await dp.start_polling()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = Thread(target=asyncio.run(check_bd()))
    start_bot = Thread(target=asyncio.run(start_bot()))

    f.start()
    start_bot.start()

    f.join()
    start_bot.join()
`
Ошибки нет, но бот не работает